# Elastic Search in PHP json file

Tags: php, json, elasticsearch

I installed Elastica PHP client and checked search data from server (localhost
:9200)`enter code here` but i would like to search data from JSON file stored in web app. The json file store data of users in web app. Is it possible to search data from JSON file using Elastic search. How can connect/index to JSON file for search?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What is this web app? Does it have an access to the Elasticsearch cluster?

Comment: I have a web application in PHP for data collection. In that, user details stored in JSON file. So for searching user details can i use this elastic search?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Do you have access to the elasticsearch cluster where the data is?